# Selenium 3.0.1, gekodriver v0.11.1, firefox 49.0.2 "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055" exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette, selenium3

Trying to upgrade to Selenium 3.0 from Selenium 2.53.  I can not put firefox in path, nor can put the gekodriver in path.  I was using this in Selenium 2:

```
String firefoxLocation = System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)") + "\\Mozilla Firefox_42\\firefox.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefoxLocation);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

This worked perfectly.  I upgraded to Selenium 3.0, installed firefox 49 and downloaded the latest geko.  I now have this:

```
String firefoxLocation = System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)") + "\\Mozilla Firefox_49\\firefox.exe";
String gekoLocation = "..\\common\\geko\\gekodriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefoxLocation);
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", gekoLocation);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Firefox opens to a blank window, then times out.  I tried instead of setting webdriver.firefox.marionette, setting webdriver.geko.driver, but got the error that I must use "webdriver.geko.driver" (which I was using).  How do I arrange it so I can specify a different firefox.exe location and a different gekodriver.exe location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spelling wrong.

try this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", gekoLocation);
```

use `gecko` instead of `geko`